# Find range of files using dates as filename and output as array

Tags: find

I have a list of files named

```
2020-01-02.csv
2020-01-03.csv
```

etc. but there will be days where these are not generated.
I can't use system timestamps for created / modified as they run over into the next day due to timezones and other reasons.

I basically need to be able to specify 2 date ranges (Start and End) as variables then output the list of found files into an array.

I have tried using this, which works if the files exist, but it fails and outputs nothing if a file doesn't exist

```
$ find -type f -newer 2020-01-02.csv ! -newer 2020-01-14.csv
find: '2020-01-07.csv': No such file or directory
```

But if I do

```
find -type f -newer 2020-01-02.csv ! -newer 2020-01-03.csv
```

I get the following output:

```
./2020-01-02.csv
./2020-01-03.csv
```

Comment: In your attempts you're still relying on system timestamps though; `-newer` compares last modification times. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: I thought newermt compares modification time and newer just does filename?

Comment: There is no `-newermt` option to `find`.

Comment: Which `find` are we talking about here? Neither GNU find has a `-newermt` flag nor POSIX lists it as a standard primary

Comment: @oguzismail @user1934428 GNU find definitively has this option. It is documented under `-newerXY`. The `m` and `t` are basically parameters.

Comment: @Socowi Yes, you're right thanks. Then OP was wrong in thinking that -newer compares filenames, right?

Comment: Yes, of course `-newer` does **not** care about the filename. How would this be supposed to work on arbitrary filenames. For instance, should the name `text.txt` be newer or older than `img.jpg`?

Comment: Yes I misunderstood how it worked when reading the documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider piping the 'find' into 'awk' perform the filtering.

If all you files are in the same folder, you can replace the `find ...` with `ls *.csv`

For large number of files, calling `date` on each file can be slow. Using  find/awk will usually be much faster.

The `awk` one-liner split the file into component based on '/' (`-F/`), than filter on the last component (`$NF`)

```
#! /bin/bash
from=2017-07-18
last=2019-07-18
find . -name '*.csv' |
 awk -F/ -v FROM="$from" -v LAST="$last" 'match($NF, "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\\.csv") && $NF >= FROM && $NF <= LAST''
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways. First is to use the filename:

```
todate=$(date -d 2019-07-18 +%s)
fromdate=$(date -d 2017-08-19 +%s)

for file in *.csv ; do
    filename=${file%.csv}
    filedate=$(date -d $filename +%s)
    if [ $filedate -ge $fromdate ] ; then
        if [ $filedate -le $todate ] ; then
            echo "Hurray for $file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

You can compact the code, but for clarity I've written it out a bit verbosely.

Another way would be to use the timestamps of the files:

```
for file in *.csv ; do
    filename=${file%.csv}
    timestamp=${filename//-/}
    touch -t $timestamp $file
done

touch -t fromfile 2020010200
touch -t tofile   2020011400
find -type f -newer fromfile ! -newer tofile
```

Comment: No need for temporary files. You can use `find -newermt 'put a date here'`.

Comment: As I said, @socowi -newermt is useles for me in this scenario as the modification date will not match the filename.

Comment: @Ljm Dullaart is there a way to make the make it so the dates in the todate and fromdate are user entered?

Comment: sure; `read -p 'From date (yyyy-mm-dd): ' fromstring` and `fromdate=$(date -d "$fromstring" +%s)` (same for todate). This is without input validation, which is something you should do if your scripts get widly deployed.